# Python multiprocessing.Manager shared data and CLI pipe

Tags: python, bash, python-multiprocessing

I've narrowed a problem I'm having down to this simple example.

This is `test.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import multiprocessing

_THREADS = 4

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def _process( work ) :
    index, shared_data = work
    print( "Thread", index )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__" :

    # Pipe output for this works.
    #shared_data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

    # Pipe output for this does not work.
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    shared_data = manager.list( [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] )

    work = [ ( index, shared_data ) for index in range( _THREADS ) ]

    print( "Processing..." )

    with multiprocessing.Pool( _THREADS ) as pool :
        pool.map( _process, work )

    print( "Done." )
```

Now if I run `test.py` and pipe the output, I don't get any output from the threaded section print statements.

```sh
$ ./test.py | cat -
Processing...
Done.
```

If I remove the shared data using `multiprocessing.Manager`, I get the expected output:

```sh
$ ./test.py | cat -
Processing...
Thread 0
Thread 1
Thread 3
Thread 2
Done.
```

Both produce the correct output if no pipe is used.  I'm not sure why using `multiprocessing.Manager` with shared data causes this.  Is there something I am missing?

EDIT:
A suggestion to flush the `print` statement did correct this problem.  So technically this problem is solved.  Anyone have an idea about why, only when shared data is used, the `print` statements in processes are no longer getting flushed?

```py
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def _process( work ) :
    index, shared_data = work
    print( "Thread", index, flush=True )
```

Comment: You'll confuse yourself if you refer to processes as threads!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah, I'm not good about using those terms correctly with Python.

Comment: You could try to add `sys.stdout.flush()` at the end of the `_process` function.

Comment: @Timus Wasn't expecting that to work, but it did.  Why `stdout` isn't flushed when the process ends only when shared memory is used is still a mystery, but doing it manually does produce the output.  Confused, but I'll take the working results.

Comment: To make it even stranger: You don't even have to use the `shared_data` (remove them from `_process` and `work`), only produce them (`shared_data = manager.list( [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] )`), to get this behaviour most of the time - not always, though.